# Setting symbology of layer made from client side graphic (ArcGIS Web AppBuilder)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

So I am using ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Developer Edition and on load of one of the widgets a layer is created using the geometry from one layer and attributes from a table. I have this completed and displaying on the map, but I need it to display in multiple colors. `features` is the graphics and attributes to add in

```
  makeLayer: function (features) {
    var featureCollection = {
      layerDefinition: {
        geometryType: "esriGeometryPoint",
        objectIdField: "OBJECTID",
      },
      featureSet: {
        features: features,
        geometryType: "esriGeometryPoint",
      }
    }

    var sitePointsSettings = {
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT
    }
    var layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, sitePointsSettings)
    layer.title = "Site Scores";
    this.map.addLayer(layer);


    this.publishData({
      siteScoresLayer: layer
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [setRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#setrenderer) method with the [Renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/renderer-amd.html) (like a [UniqueValueRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/uniquevaluerenderer-amd.html)) you've created to change the colors of the feature layer.

Comment: already figured it out the field the renderer was using wasn't created correctly at first. do you by chance know how i would turn on popups for the above layer? I've tried just about everything